# CSS Gradient Not Working In Chrome 49

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm to use a linear gradient as the background for my `body`. It ***works in Safari but not in Chrome***. I've searched Stack Overflow and nothing has worked so far for me. It has only worked in browsers other than Chrome (Chrome 49).

The code I'm trying to use is made from a generator that is meant to support all browsers.

```
body {
    background: rgba(121, 91, 176, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1)), color-stop(92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#795bb0', endColorstr='#4ceaff', GradientType=1);
}
```

Below is the HTML to reproduce the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Site</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- JS WARN -->
    <div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Verpz/Javascript-Disabled-Warning-Popup/b10b9ebe28a92ffe746eb7e6fb6e0d3497c3afdd/js-warn.css">
      <input type="checkbox" id="js-hide" />
      <div class="js-warn" id="js-warn-exit"><h1>Javascript Is Disabled</h1><p>Javascript seems to be disabled. This will break some site features.</p>
      <p>To enable Javascript click <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">here</a></p><label for="js-hide">Close</label></div>
      <script>var jswarn = document.getElementById("js-warn-exit"); jswarn.parentNode.removeChild(jswarn);</script>
    </div>
    <!-- /JS WARN -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have v49 but in the previous version and the latest dev-m v50 version it is working fine. What output are you seeing? Can you recreate that in a fiddle and show us?

Comment: I get a blank screen. Nothing at all happens. https://jsfiddle.net/dye0vvky/1/ It works fine in other browsers and in the fiddle.

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dye0vvky/2/) work in your Chrome? Or do you still see the blank page?

Comment: Would you like me to test the css in the fiddle?

Comment: The fiddle provided was incomplete - https://jsfiddle.net/dye0vvky/3/ this works in **Chrome - Version 49.0.2623.87 m**

Comment: @Verpz: First does the fiddle produce the required output? Next try that in your page.

Comment: The fiddles work, they show up fine. But on a local html file it doesn't work. The same file works on other browsers however.

Comment: @Verpz: Unless we can see the problem, we can't debug it.

Comment: Would you like my html and css file?

Comment: Yes, post it and we will see if it is of any help.

Comment: Sorry this is a pretty bad way to share it, but I can't use JSFiddle because it doesn't accept <head> tags etc. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6U713Fn8h8rSXdkX3dxMGFlMUk&usp=sharing @Harry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106784/discussion-between-verpz-and-harry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the `body` tag by itself doesn't have any height and so the gradients won't show up and we have to either add some content to it (or) give it some explicit height. Adding a fixed height value may not always be possible and so it is better to add a `min-height: 100vh` (that is, the height will atleast be as much as the viewport's height).

**Note:** The behavior is consistent across IE, Edge, Firefox and Chrome. I am trying to find why Safari handles it differently. I will edit the information into the answer once I have it.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(121, 91, 176, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1)), color-stop(92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(121, 91, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(74, 193, 255, 1) 66%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 92%, rgba(76, 234, 255, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#795bb0', endColorstr='#4ceaff', GradientType=1);
}
```